# How to optimize if there are too many sql subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql

If the table database is like this

device table

````
```
device_id device_uuid device_status
1001      00000       offline
1002      00000       Online
1003      11111       Offline
1004      11111       Offline
```
````

task table

````
```
task_id device_id task_value
50001   1001      Cleaning
50002   1001      Cleaning
50003   1004      Cleaning
```
````

my sql

```
select t.* 
from task t 
where t.device_id in (select device_id 
                      from device d1 
                      where d1.device_uuid in (select device_uuid 
                                               from device d 
                                               where d.device_status = 'online'
                                              )
                     )
```

How to optimize? Thanks!

Comment: Hint : `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` or `EXISTS` :

```
select t.* 
from task t 
where exists (select 1 
              from device d1 
              where d1.device_id = t.device_id and 
                    d1.device_status = 'online'
             );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the result of your sql execution is different from mine. I hope device_uuid only needs to query an online record in the device table, then all device_ids corresponding to this device_uuid should meet the conditions

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOINs`.  Mimic your thoughts -- "first find the 'online' devices, then ...":

```
SELECT  t.*
    FROM  device d
    JOIN  device d1 USING(device_uuid)
    JOIN  task t USING(device_id)
    WHERE  d.device_status = 'online';
```

I'm unclear on the need for touching `device` twice.  Maybe this would suffice:

```
SELECT  t.*
    FROM  device d
    JOIN  task t USING(device_id)
    WHERE  d.device_status = 'online';
```

A note:

```
FROM a JOIN b  USING(x)
```

is a shorthand for

```
FROM a JOIN b  ON b.x = a.x
```

There is another issue -- Indexes.  Be sure to have these; if the tables are large, they will help significantly:

```
device:  INDEX(device_status, device_id)
task:    INDEX(device_id)
```

Another note:  the keywords `INNER` and `OUTER` have no functionality in MySQL, hence I left them out.